# Why when I pressed notification, but PendingIntent didn't go to another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Why when I pressed notification, but `PendingIntent` didn't go to `DetailMessageRecyclerViewFragment`?? I tried a lot but failed.

MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    private var userAvatarByteArray: Bitmap? = null

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

        val imgsGroupId = remoteMessage.data["imgsGroupId"]
        val notificationContent = remoteMessage.data["messageContent"]
        val userAvatarUrl = remoteMessage.data["userAvatarUrl"]

        val messageSenderAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(userAvatarUrl)
        /*userAvatarUrl?.toByteArray().let {
            userAvatarByteArray = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(it, 0, it!!.size)
        }*/

        createNotificationChannel()

        val intent = Intent(this, DetailMessageRecyclerViewFragment::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            putExtra("imgsGroupId",imgsGroupId)
        }

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0,
            intent,
            0
        )
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_message_24)
            .setContentText(notificationContent)
            .setLargeIcon(messageSenderAvatar)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build()

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        }
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                MESSAGE_CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).apply {
                enableLights(true)
                lightColor = Color.CYAN

            }
            val notificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }

    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
    }
}
```

DetailMessageRecyclerViewFragment.kt

```
class DetailMessageRecyclerViewFragment : Fragment(R.layout.detail_message_recycler_view_fragment) {

    private var uploadedImagesFromNotification: UploadedImages? = null
    private var imgsGroupId: String? = null

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
imgsGroupId = activity?.intent?.getStringExtra("imgsGroupId")

        if (imgsGroupId != null) {
            Firebase.firestore.collection("uploadedImages").document(imgsGroupId!!)
                .get().addOnSuccessListener {
                    uploadedImagesFromNotification = it.toObject(UploadedImages::class.java)
                }
        }

//Get notification to get message
        if (uploadedImagesFromNotification != null) {
            detailMessageViewModel.getUploadedMessage(uploadedImagesFromNotification!!).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                images_messages_recycyler_view.apply {
                    setHasFixedSize(true)
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    adapter = DetailMessageRecyclerAdapter(it, uploadedImagesFromNotification!!).apply {
                        notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            })
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot build an `Intent` to launch a `Fragment`. You build an `Intent` to launch an `Activity`. The `Activity` can then decide what `Fragment` to show. This code is not valid:

```
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailMessageRecyclerViewFragment::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        putExtra("imgsGroupId",imgsGroupId)
    }

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0,
        intent,
        0
    )
```

Comment: OK!! Thank you!!

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, you should accept it by clicking on the green checkmark next to the answer. This will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions and also improve your "acceptance rate". I also get reputation points for an accepted answer. These are good things for both the one who asks the question and the one who answers.

Comment: OK! After I tried your method with no problem, I will check checkmark for your answer. Thank you again.